# Puts() and Gets() does not work when used after scanf()

Tags: scanf, gets, puts

It seems that the `puts()` and `gets()` functions do not work if I use `scanf()` before `gets()` and `puts()`. Please see code below.

If I delete the section before, `puts()` and `gets()` work okay. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int numberOutcomes;
    char outcomeOne[50];

    printf("How many outcomes do you have on your form?\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numberOutcomes);
    printf("The number of outcomes you have on your form is %d\n", numberOutcomes);

    printf("Type in your first outcome then press Enter. For example: good outcome or bad outcome.\n");
    gets(outcomeOne);

    puts(outcomeOne);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First piece of advice, don't use `gets()` - there is *no* way to use it safely so as to avoid potential buffer overflow (it's one of the *few* things that have even been removed from the ISO standard, as of C11). Instead, use `fgets()`, which *can* limit what's read in.

As to your *specific* problem, `scanf(" %d", &numberOutcomes)` will, after skipping whitespace, consume enough characters in the input stream to populate `numberOutcomes`, *and no more.* Importantly, it will *not* consume trailing whitespace such as the `\n` character that was put there when you pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to submit your input.

Hence, on the `gets()` call, it will simply get a blank line.

*Both* of those problems can be solved in you choose *either* the `scanf()`-style input or line-based input. For the former case, scanning the next item will (usually) skip the whitespace in the input stream, for the latter, reading lines reads the whole line including trailing whitespace.

You can *make* it work by mixing the two but it's a bit more effort.

My advice would be to use line-based input for everything and then `sscanf` specific data out of the string you read. This has the advantages of:

- avoiding the exact problem you've found; and
- allowing you to `sscanf` multiple times on the same line if you need to handle multiple line formats.

For that, a rock-solid line-input routine (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921)) is very handy.